# How to shorten android package name?

Tags: android, android-studio

My package name now... 
**com.dairy.iconic.ais.demo.tanim**

I want to shorten my android package name to
**com.dairy.iconic**

But how it is possible ? 
I need Solution. Please.

Comment: You can rename the package...

Comment: But com.dairy.iconic.ais.demo.tanim....here are every word create as a folder inside each folder  If I go to com" folder then I see dairy" folder then see iconic" folder....as like each word.

Comment: You can rename them, right click, refactor -> rename package/directory

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In android studio close all opened files and try below steps.

1. Rename applicationID in build.gradle file in app/build.gradle and click save
2. Copy your java or other files from old location com/dairy/iconic/ais/demo/tanim to com/dairy/iconic (In disc not in studio)
3. Delete ais, demo and tanim folders
4. In android studio - File/Invalidate cache and restart.

Comment: Welcome friend !

Answer (score 0):

Right-click on your package com.dairy.iconic.ais.demo.tanim from Project Panel.
Then,
Choose Refactor and finally rename the package name.

You will warn to do refactoring the package name. Just agree and click on Do Refactor.

Don't forget to see the changes effect on Manifest, .Gradle file

Comment: it does not shorten the package, only replace some word to another

Answer (score -1):

You can change Project name and  Package name also.

**Change Package Name :**

Right Click on Project >Android Tools >Rename Application Package

Then go to src and right click on your main package >Refactor >Rename

And finally go to manifest file and change your package name .

**Change Project Name :**

Right click on Project Refactor >Rename

Comment: it does not shorten the package, only replace some word to another